# switchto.defaultcontent() method not working with chromedriver 99.0.434

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

Problem: On a web page> + icon>clicking on it>opens a small widget on same page. it has iframe to access the fields, so switch to iframe. after this need to click on a button which does not come under any iframe. So I was trying to come out of iframe by `switchto().defaultcontent()` but this is not working. And as a result that button is not found.

Comment: Missing basic debugging details... Please share all your actual code including a link to the page you are working on

Comment: In the below code we switch to frame:

Comment: Please put all this into your question to make it readable. Also we need a link to that page

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that with Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver v99 switchTo().DefaultContent() is not working, once you selected a new frame switchTo.Frame(1)